# Difference between solidcolorbrush and brush

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

What is the the differnce between solidcolorbrush and brush, In WPF (C#).

```
SolidColorBrush br = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

and

```
Brush br = Brushes.Red;
```

Comment: What is the problem here? Have you read [WPF Brushes Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ??

Comment: Use Visual Studio's "Go To Implementation" function (right click on the type name for Brush and SolidColorBrush) and you have answered your own question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question **No difference**.

`Brushes.Red` returns `SolidColorBrush` only. Its definition is like:

```
public static SolidColorBrush Red { get; }
```

You can assume its default template which Microsoft provides you for basic colors.

---

Use SolidColorBrush constructor in case you want to provide your own **custom A,R,G,B** values for color.

This will get you actual `Red` color:

[image]

```
SolidColorBrush anotherBrush = 
                     new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
```

This will get you Red color with `G` component set to `100 byte` and `B` component set to `50 byte`.

[image]

```
SolidColorBrush anotherBrush = 
                     new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 100, 50));
```

Answer (score 3):

None.

MSDN says:

```
public static SolidColorBrush Red { get; }
```

So in fact this is a static SolidColorBrush. With your first line of code you create a similar object.

Answer (score 1):

Brush is the base class and holds any type of brush no matter how it was created. SolidColorBrush constructs a brush having a solid Color, LinearGradientBrush is another way to constract a brush and there are by far more. And WPF offers a huge set of predefined brushes in the Brushes class. They are of type SolidColorBrush just in order to say: a single, solid color.